# Using IF loop and monotonic data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to select specific data within a time vector to assign a specific start point.

```
Vit_lim = 5*(max(dcursor))/100
A = find(dcursor > Vit_lim)

A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 158 159 160.........318]
```

The start point is being dectected as first value.

The initial 8 values are a false positive (and do not represent real start point (158).

I need to add a condition that finds start point if first value increases monotonically for 20 consecutive values.

This is within a larger loop.

Comment: Can you please post the full code..  what is dcursor? It appears as though it is less than 1.

Comment: Can you provide a typical `dcursor` and `Vit_lim` data?

Comment: Hi guys, below suggestion worked for me. Thanks for all getting back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 158 159 160.........318]

found=0;
idx=1;
monoticSum=0;
tempValue=A(1);
idx=2;

While found == 0
temp=A(idx);
if ((tempValue+1) == temp)
  monoticSum = monoticSum+1;
  tempValue = temp;
else
  monoticSum = 0
end
if (monoticSum == 20)
  found=1;
  break
end
idx=idx+1
end
```

This should work.
Actually, this is a nice starting point. But you need to restart the variable monoticSum if you find any transition less than 20. I've updated.

Comment: @DavidGaul can you please check the answer correct then? thanks! :)

Comment: @DavidGaul can you please check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 20 consecutive values, given that your sample data has 8 false-start values.  But here's an idea that finds a sample that's at least 20 away from the previous

```
b=find(diff(A)>20);
start_idx = A(b+1);
```